# Audit shows a different user

Tags: bug, review-audits, triage

I was completing reviews in the Triage review queue and had this question:

[image]

...your bog standard spam question.

I marked it as `Unsalvageable` and flagged it as `spam`, and I got this:

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You passed**.

*...ok, job done.*

I go into my review history a few minutes later to find the audit **isn't there**, but luckily I still had the Triage queue open so [I went back to the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6876516)... and find that instead of my user, it instead lists *another* user:

[image]

I had a chat with [BradleyDotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619) and we both agree that it's a bug, *unless* the other user and myself managed to get the *same* audit at the *same* time, which doesn't seem probable.

The bug seems to be that the system has managed to get my user ID mixed up with that of another user, and I checked when that user was online via the `Last Seen` and they didn't appear to be online in Stack Overflow at the time the audit was completed as the *audit* was completed two hours ago and the *user* was last seen three hours ago.

I have also attempted to contact the other user (Afract) to confirm that they *didn't* complete this audit, but I've had no response so far, probably too soon.

Is this a bug, or just some confusing mix-up?

Comment: Note that review histories are public http://stackoverflow.com/users/461444/afract?tab=activity&sort=reviews - I don't see it in that listing.

Comment: @MichaelT Looks like it's definitely a bug, then.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Looks like Geoff didn't read the specifics in the question, nor any of the comments (nor the answer). Raised a custom flag to revert since the system isn't allowing me to edit the tag out (or roll back).

Comment: To be clear, @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ, this may not be fixable - and if it is, it may not be worth fixing.

Comment: Maybe a `status-very-low-roi`? The type of thing to give to an intern to see if they can do it, but if not that's ok too.

Comment: @MichaelT Probably better suited to [meta-tag:status-deferred].

Comment: @Shog9 Surely it's a matter of checking if only the user has an audit open? Perhaps even better, assign an audit to a user *before* it actually happens.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. Normally you only get assigned someone else's review if they've *abandoned it*.

Comment: I just had this happen to me!  I was in the close votes queue, and passed an audit.  I noticed that the review count didn't increase, so I clicked back, and saw that the audit was attributed to someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8816068  It's also not in my review history.... looks like we both passed the same Audit at the same time, and this bug is still alive and well.

Answer (score 23):

I checked the logs; Afract *was* reviewing during the same time period you were, and *did* complete that audit. Confusingly, you were assigned the *same* audit while he was reviewing it, and submitted your review a few seconds after he submitted his.

You both passed the audit, but only his review was recorded.

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: Then two questions: why isn't the audit in their review log and shouldn't the system be giving out *different* audits?

Comment: I originally thought the system blocks this type of thing from happening, and I still think this is a bug. The bug here now is 'why did the system give an identical audit to two different users at the same time?'.

Comment: I would tend to consider it a bug as well. To be clear, you didn't get identical audits - you got *the same* audit. Lots of other people got identical audits, and their passes/failures were logged on their own - you got a task that someone else was already doing. Oh, and audits backed by deleted posts don't usually show up in review logs.

Comment: @Shog9 But at the same time, that's not normal is it?

Comment: No, it's not normal.

Comment: @MichaelT There are only two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation and naming things.